# How to create two edges out of an edge?

Tags: modeling, workflow, edges

I'm having trouble modeling a somewhat simple shape. What I currently have is this:

[image]

And what I'm trying to get is this:

[image]

What would be a way to do this? I can't just extrude the bottom faces, because I want them to stay connected to the main body of what I'm modeling. I'd like to do this without any ngons or hacky tricks, it seems like something that should be fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways to model this; if original shape should be preserved, the steps may be as follows.

1. Select bottom edge which you'd like to make 2 from. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to extend vertices.

   [image: extending edges - image]
2. Select 2 resulting Ngons, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate them, and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to get rid of tris and convert them to quads.

   [image: converting to tris and quads]
3. Add loopcut to refine model, dissolve resulting and not needed edges.

   [image: refining model]

Answer (score 0):

What I would do
[[image: b[![][1]]]
add edgeloop CTRL+R
[image]
scale face down 
[image]
move the edge upward

Comment: The problem is that I can't create an edgeloop in that location because of the way my geometry is. Look carefully at the edges in my original pictures